# How do I run Testacular on Windows?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

Working on Windows (x86 version, not cygwin)

I was able to install Testacular

npm list -g

```
C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\npm
└─┬ testacular@0.4.0
  etc....
```

But when I run testacular get ...

'testacular' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have tried adding bin to path..

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\testacular\bin
```

but it doesn't work, there does not appear to be an executeable or batch file (testacular.bat, testacular.exe)

What am I missing?

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `testacular.cmd` :-)

In the command prompt, simply type `testacular.cmd` instead of just `testacular`.  You must do the same for many node modules on windows.

Comment: Can you add an explanation? Or else change this to a comment.

Comment: Added more explanation :-)

Comment: there is no testacular.cmd in my testacular installation.  still confused.

Comment: The problem turned out to be the path setting.. There IS a testacular.cmd, it just wasn't where I expected it to be.  Fixed it by doing this... SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\npm  If this path is set then you can just go ahead and use 'testacular' as per all the docs etc.

Comment: ..which is now known as karma. From the cmd/powershell use just karma instead of testacular.